# Spring Security: How to programmatically define forwarding logic if a user isn't authenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using programmitic (not xml) configuration to configure spring security. By default, if a user is trying to access a protected resource without being logged in he gets forwarded to the login page. However, I need to write some custom logic instead of always redirecting to the login page. Is there a way to configure this?

```
http.antMatcher("/protected/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()...
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume you use `Basic authentication` for http, you should configure an `EntryPoint`, then you can get the `HttpServletRequest`object.

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.getDispatcherServlet().forward()...
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + getRealmName() + "\"");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName(WebSecurityConfig.REALM);
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Then add the following to spring security config:

```
.and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());
```